# Is there a way to json_encode only to a certain depth?

Tags: php, json

For example, I may have an array that contains strings that are json elements. If I want to json_encode this array I have to first json_decode the elements that are json strings and then json_encode the array. Otherwise, I will be encoding already encoded json.

Comment: You mean like this `["{\"key\":\"value\"}","{\"amount\": 5, \"cpu\":\"$0.25\"}"]`

Comment: Why are they being encoded in the first place?